# ¿Comó usar un ArrayList dentro de un objeto en itext 7?

Tags: java, arraylist, objeto, itext

**Hola comunidad gracias por su apoyo de antemano, estoy implementando itext7 para generar documentación, añadí un constructor con mis métodos Setters y Getters. Cuando almaceno mis argumentos dentro del objeto lo mando a agrego en un ArrayList para imprimirlo dentro de mi documento PDF o consola, el problema es que solo almacena el ultimo objeto dentro de mi ArrayList y este al ejecutarse en mi for me imprime una y otra vez el mismo en vez de añadir la secuencia de objetos, alguien sabra si es por el tipo de Arraylist o lo estoy usando mal ya que mi ciclo for no es el problema**

```
public class Pdf {
    public static final String path = ".Documentation/Evidence.pdf";
    public static final String QA = "./QA.jpg";
    public static java.util.List<ArchivoTexto> listaPdf = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        File file = new File(path);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        java.util.List<ArchivoTexto> listaPdf = new ArrayList<ArchivoTexto>();

        ArchivoTexto caso1 = new ArchivoTexto("Prueba 1 de app", "1DWwv bgf");
        listaPdf.add(caso1);

        ArchivoTexto caso2 = new ArchivoTexto("Execucion 2 de app", "2");
        listaPdf.add(caso2);

        Documentation(path);
    }

    public static void Documentation(String dest) throws Exception {


        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

        //Static name tableHeader
        float[] columnWidths = {1, 5, 2};
        Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(columnWidths));

        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(i))));
            table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(ArchivoTexto.getDescription()))));
            table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(ArchivoTexto.getExpected()))));
        }

        //Number of pages
        int numberOfPages = pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {

        document.add(table);

        document.close();
    }
}

public class ArchivoTexto {

    private static String description;
    private static String expected;

    public ArchivoTexto(String description, String expected){
        this.description = description;
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    public static String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public static String getExpected() {
        return expected;
    }

    public void setExpected(String expected) {
        this.expected = expected;
    }
}
```

[image: Consola]
[image: PDF]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Listo he solucionado mi conflicto eliminando de las variables y métodos getters el "static", dentro de mi main aumentar un objeto sin argumento para que en el for comenzara a partir del 1 y menos que mi ArrayList.**

```
 public class Pdf {
        public static final String path = ".Documentation/Evidence.pdf";
    
        public static java.util.List<ArchivoTexto> listaPdf = new ArrayList<>();
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
            File file = new File(path);
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    
            ArchivoTexto caso1 = new ArchivoTexto("Prueba 1 de app", "1DWwv bgf");
            listaPdf.add(caso1);
    
            ArchivoTexto caso2 = new ArchivoTexto("Execucion 2 de app", "2");
            listaPdf.add(caso2);
    
            ArchivoTexto caso3 = new ArchivoTexto("Execucion 3 de app", "2ref45rtcf");
            listaPdf.add(caso3);
    
            ArchivoTexto caso4 = new ArchivoTexto("Execucion 4 de app", "2cadfv ");
            listaPdf.add(caso4);
    
            ArchivoTexto caso5 = new ArchivoTexto("Execucion 5 de app", "22315rtfcq3 ");
            listaPdf.add(caso5);

/*
Utilizo la siguientes lineas para que me imprima el valor de mi Array llamándolo desde el ArrayList
*/

            //Getting Iterator
            Iterator itr=listaPdf.iterator();
            //traversing elements of ArrayList object
            while(((Iterator<?>) itr).hasNext()){
                ArchivoTexto st=(ArchivoTexto) ((Iterator<?>) itr).next();
                System.out.println(st.getDescription()+" "+st.getExpected());
            }
    
            System.out.println("Hay " + listaPdf.size() + " renglones");
    
            Documentation(path);
        }
         public static void Documentation(String dest) throws Exception {
    
    
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
            Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
    
            //Static name tableHeader
            float[] columnWidths = {1, 5, 2};
            Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(columnWidths));
    
            for (int i = 1; i < listaPdf.size(); i++) {
                table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(i))));
                table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(listaPdf.get(i).getDescription()))));
                table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(listaPdf.get(i).getExpected()))));
             }

            document.add(table);
    
            document.close();
        }
    }
            package Documentation;
    
    public class ArchivoTexto {
    
        private String description;
        private String expected;
    
        public ArchivoTexto(String description, String expected){
            this.description = description;
            this.expected = expected;
        }
    
        public String getDescription() {
            return this.description;
        }
    
        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
    
        public String getExpected() {
            return this.expected;
        }
    
        public void setExpected(String expected) {
            this.expected = expected;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En las siguientes líneas, estás accediendo a los atributos del objeto ArchivoTexto directamente.

Si quieres acceder a los valores del array, debes pasar el array como parámetro en tu método "Documentation"

```
public static void Documentation(String dest, List<ArchivoTexto> listaPdf)
```

Y en el for donde mapeas la información debes iterar el array y acceder a los atributos del objeto, utilizando sus respectivos métodos de acceso:

```
for (int i = 0; i< listaPdf.size(); i++) {
    table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(i+1))));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(listaPdf.get(i).getDescription()))));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(listaPdf.get(i).getExpected()))));
}
```

En el main, debes invocar el método Documentation de la siguiente forma

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        File file = new File(path);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        java.util.List<ArchivoTexto> listaPdf = new ArrayList<ArchivoTexto>();

        ArchivoTexto caso1 = new ArchivoTexto("Prueba 1 de app", "1DWwv bgf");
        listaPdf.add(caso1);

        ArchivoTexto caso2 = new ArchivoTexto("Execucion 2 de app", "2");
        listaPdf.add(caso2);

        Documentation(path, listaPdf);
    }
```

Como recomendación, trabaja un poco mejor el principio de encapsulamiento:

[Principio de encapsulamiento](https://juanjavierrg.com/java-basico-encapsulamiento/#:%7E:text=En%20encapsulamiento%20es%20un%20principio,m%C3%A9todos%20que%20la%20controlan%20p%C3%BAblicos.)

Quita el label static a los atributos y métodos de la clase ArchivoTexto.

Espero te haya servido de ayuda.

Comment: Hola a lo que mencionas lo intente pero se genera un conflicto con el dentro des mis atributos ya que el  la linea del main 

Documentation(path); //genera un error en los atributos, en este caso "dest" es String y "list" es un Array, y me pide cambiar "path" como Array.

He solucionado el problema de almacenamiento dejándolo sin Static en las el variables, constructor y métodos de encapsulamiento puedo hacer impresión de los argumentos desde la consola pero el problema es de ITEXT 7 ya que no añade el array dentro de las celdas

Comment: @IsraelSanz He modificado la respuesta para que te guíes un poco. El problema de como lo estás implementando y que solo te trae el último registro, se debe a que estás llamando directamente a la clase ArchivoTexto  y estás accediendo directamente a sus atributos, por ende solo traerá el último valor asignado, que corresponde al que declaras al hacer un new ArchivoTexto